# Error with splice method: can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to insert a string value inside an array with 3 string values randomly. But it gives this error in console:

`*Uncaught TypeError: can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length*`

After assigning `obj.incorrect_answers` to `answers`, the length of the array will be 3, and I try to insert `correct_answer`(that is a string) in an index between 0 to 3.

It's desired part of my code:

```
export const Home = () => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(0);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const obj = useSelector((state) => state.questions.data[id]);
    const fetchStatus = useSelector((state) => state.questions.status);
    if(obj){
        let answers = obj.incorrect_answers;
        answers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*4), 0, obj.correct_answer);
        console.log(answers);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(fetchStatus === "idle"){
            dispatch(fetchQuestions());
        }
    }, [fetchStatus])
```

`obj` is received from the server, but I know it's received correctly because when I console.log `obj.incorrect_answers` it gives me an array from 3 strings and when I console.log `obj.correct_answer` it gives me a string, correctly. So I think I just have a problem with `splice` method.

Maybe, it is relevant to receive data from the server, but I can see received data in the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed by [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) Only by changing:

```
let answers = obj.incorrect_answers;
```

to:

```
let answers = obj.incorrect_answers.slice();
```

Comment: This looks interesting. can you explain why it works?

Comment: @HasanAli I really don't know, but probably the length of the original array isn't changeable, for any reason, so when I slice that, it is a new copy and I can change it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error message, it seems you have a read-only `length` prop on your array! try to make it writable: `Object.defineProperty(answers, 'length', { writable: true });`

An alternative way of getting the same result is to insert to the end of the array, then simply [shuffle the array](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-shuffle-array-javascript/).

```
 if(obj){
        let answers = obj.incorrect_answers;
        answers.push(obj.correct_answer)
        answers.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        console.log(answers);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives the same error again, and it is strange!! Probably there are some ways to replace it, but I want to know why that doesn't work.

Comment: Judging by the error message, it seems you have read-only `length` prop on your array! try to make it writable: `Object.defineProperty(answers, 'length', { writable: true });`

Comment: I didn't understand exactly how and where I should use it, but my error is fixed and it also works by your suggestion about `push` and then `sort`, thank you :)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same error, but it only showed up when I added in useDispatch(). In my use case, I'm only setting it to useDispatch to provide props down the line, and when I go without, all my other functionality holds true, but the props aren't available. After trying other array methods and getting the same result, I'm guessing it has to do with redux's interaction with the array